# Getting Error: ngModel:nonassign Non-Assignable Expression In AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm having a stressful moment in trying to this figure this out but i'm looping through an array using ng-repeat in my view like this:

```
//Array from controller  that i'm receiving from a server 

    $scope.data =[{Day: 'Monday', startTime: '2016-03-29T12:30:00', finishTime: '2016-03-29T16:30:00'},
    [{Day: 'Tuesday', startTime: '2016-03-29T12:00:00', finishTime: '2016-03-29T18:00:00'},
       ]
//Then looping through like this:

    <div ng-repeat="a in data track by $index">

    <input ng-model="a.day">
    <input ng-model="a.startTime | data: 'hh:mm'">
    <input ng-model="a.finishTime | data: 'hh:mm'">

    </div>
```

As you can see above i'm filtering the date to only show the time. The filtration  through pipes work fine and the time is displayed , but i get this error message:

> Expression 'a.startTime |' is non-assignable. Element: {1}

If i only needed to display the value i'd do the following

```
<input value={{a.startTime | date: 'hh:mm'}}
```

but in this case i also need to get the values from textfields hence why i'm using ng-model.

I can't even edit the time in the textboxes due to this error . 
What is the best possible  solution to bind/assing the time in the textfield?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need a directive for that. Something like

```
module.directive('youDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
            if (!controller) {
                return;
            }

            controller.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {});

            controller.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {});
        }
    };
});
```

where in `$formatters` you format the view-value, and in `$parsers` you parse the view value for model.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by next way:

1) convert date to Date object

```
$scope.data =[{Day: 'Monday', startTime: new Date('2016-03-29T12:30:00'),....
```

2) Use input[date] directive

```
<input type="date" ng-model="a.startTime">
```

See [doc here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)